# Hibernate many to many mapping

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I have an existing database modeled the following way:

**Student** - `SchoolId(PK)`, `StudentId(PK)`, `StudentName`

**Teacher** - `SchoolId(PK)`, `TeacherId(PK)`, `TeacherName`

**Student_Teacher** - `SchoolId(PK)`, `StudentId(PK)`, `TeacherId(PK)`

Foreign key references exist from `Student_Teacher` to respective entities.

Now I am creating hibernate entities for this existing database. And I am running into weird issues creating Many-to-Many mapping from Student to Teacher.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    @EmbeddableId
    private StudentPK itemId;

    @Column(name="StudentName")
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="Student_Teacher", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SchoolId", referencedColumnName="SchoolId"),@JoinColumn(name="StudentId", referencedColumnName="StudentId")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SchoolId", referencedColumnName="SchoolId"),@JoinColumn(name="TeacherId", referencedColumnName="TeacherId")})
    private List<Teacher> attachments=new ArrayList<Teacher>();
}
```

The above code compains about some duplicate `SchoolId` reference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As I see that there is an issue in your mapping of entities, It should be as follows

***school*** -  `school_id(PK)`, `school_name`

***student*** -  `student_id(PK)` , `student_name`, `fk_school_id(FK)`,

***teacher*** - `teacher_id(PK)`, `teacher_name` , `fk_school_id(FK)`

***student_teacher*** - `student_teacher_id(PK)`, `fk_student_id(FK)`, `fk_teacher_id(FK)`

and Entity clasess as follows

**School Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column (name = "school_id")
   private int Id;

    @Column(name="school_name")
    private String schoolName;  

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "school")
   private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>  

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "school")
   private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher> 
}
```

**Student Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "student_id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="student_name")
    private String studentName;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", nullable = false)
   private School school;       

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_teacher", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_student_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_teacher_id") })
    private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

}
```

**Teacher Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "teacher_id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="teacher_name")
    private String name;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", nullable = false)
   private School school;   

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_teacher", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_teacher_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_student_id") })
    private List<Student> students =new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

hope this will solve this problem..

as you have declare **'SchoolId'** as ***PK*** in **Student_Teacher** table it will not allow you to add duplicate entry for **SchoolId** field for **Student_Teacher** table and this is not the case. thus the above relationship will gives *duplicate SchoolId reference*. when you are going to add two different students from same school into **Student_Teacher** table..

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the various PKs per entity as compound keys, as i note that you use multiple PKs per entity.  Is there any constraint why you can't use a sole PK per entity and just use a relation table to bind the 2 entities?